# force:createRecord event is returning wrong record type label

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

This functionality went live a couple of months ago and everything was working fine until recent release.

When user selects record type and click on **Next** it would run the below function.

```
handleRTselection : function(component, event, helper) {
    if(component.get("v.recTypeId") !== undefined){
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
            console.log(recId);
            console.log(recId.startsWith('500'));
            console.log(component.get("v.recTypeId"));
        if(recId.startsWith('500')){
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": "Milestone1_Task__c",
                "defaultFieldValues": {
                    'RecordTypeId' : component.get("v.recTypeId"),
                    'Case__c' : recId
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log(component.get("v.recTypeId"));
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": "Milestone1_Task__c",
                "defaultFieldValues": {
                    'RecordTypeId' : component.get("v.recTypeId"),
                    'Project_Milestone__c' : recId
                }
            });
        }
        createRecordEvent.fire();
        component.set("v.rtPopup",false);
    }
 }
```

[image: record type selection]

The layout which is being shown is correct but the record type label on the **top** is showing default record type on the users profile irrespective of what the user has chosen for.

[image]

Comment: Could you show the code where force:createRecord is actually being used?

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a possible solution. Recordtypeid should not be in default values, it should be outside.

```
createRecordEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Milestone1_Task__c",
    'recordTypeId' : component.get("v.recTypeId"),
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        'Case__c' : recId
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the recordTypeId field name is case sensitive so it should be indeed written as "recordTypeId" not "RecordTypeId"

Found this mentioned in the answer to this post in [developer forum](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eMguQAE).